# Include using local path

Tags: php

I need to include a file in a page,
usually I do this:

```
<?php 
include("/homes3/sub94/sc9493/www/app/webroot/img/include1.php"); 
?>
```

But I would like to use the Path from the bootstrap,
to have more clear code, for example something like this:

```
<?php 
include(SRC_LOCAL_PATH.'/adv-japan.php'); 
?>
```

**Why it doesn't work?**

I know I can do something like
$path= SRC_LOCAL_PATH.....
but I would like to know if I can just write one line of code, without the variable to get the path, so I would like to have something like:

..
Please note that with this:

```
<?php
echo SCR_LOCAL_PATH;
?>
```

the result is the correct path taken from bootstrap:
`/homes3/sub94/sc9493/www/app/webroot/img/`

Comment: You mention both `SRC_LOCAL_PATH` and `SCR_LOCAL_PATH`, (SRC vs SCR) are you sure it's not that typo that breaks it?

Comment: why absolute positions, why not relative?

Comment: @Topener Why do you write an absolute address in your letters, not a relative one like "third building to the right from *here*"?

Answer (score 1):

> Why it doesn't work?

That's simple.

It's either a typo in the constant's name or incorrect path. Or something of the kind.
Just check the spelling and such.

*Hint:* an error message often helps. A lot.